# Grabbing the content of a span in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

On my shopify product page I have set it so when I click on a color swatch, the color selection is printed out.  It follows the principles of this article:

https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/product-page/add-variant-sku

My second goal is, for when one of the colors is selected, I can print out the page.content of a page that has the description of that color.

The issue that I ran into is that when I try to set a variable (in .liquid) to equal the color that is being printed out, I cannot grab the content because it is being passed from a .js file to the .liquid file through a class (the actual content of the span in .liquid is empty).

Here is an example of the code so that you can understand:

The .js file

```html
if (variant.option1) {
          
          var fabric = variant.title;
      fabric = fabric.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase(); //new object assigned to var str
      
          var fabricContent = fabric
      
          
          $('.variant-fabric-name').text(variant.option1);
          
          if (variant.title) {
          
           $('.variant-fabric-description').text(fabricContent);
          }
```

The .liquid file.

```html
{% if product.options[0] %}
      
      {% capture my_variable %}<span class="variant-fabric-description"></span>{% endcapture %}


      <p class="customer-links"> <span class="variant-fabric-name"></span>: {{ pages[my_variable].content }}</p>
      
      {% endif %}
```

I've taken the variant title and made it lowercase and put a dash in between the words so that it can be a page handle that I can create and match up to.

As you can see I'm trying to get the value of fabricContent (the page handle) into the .liquid variable my_variable so I can enter it into the page[page].content code, but I cannot because the span is actually empty.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here.  Liquid is only a back-end templating system correct?  So you can't use front end javascript to fill the span and then retroactively grab the value and stick it in the .liquid file.

EDIT: Is there any reason you don't use javascript to add the variable after the span?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I dont believe I can use any front end java because it would not be in the correct function that tells the variable to change based on the variant that is selected.